# .Split() method for parsing url paths python

Tags: python, django, parsing

How can I split urls like this (which are coming from a django object selection):

```
[<PathsOfDomain: www.somesite.com/>, <PathsOfDomain: somesite.com/prof.php?pID=589>, <PathsOfDomain: www.somesite.com/some/path/here/paramid=6, <PathsOfDomain: www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=317>, <PathsOfDomain: www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=523>]
```

**I have code:**

```
if self.path_object is not None:
    dictpath = {}
    for path in self.path_object:
        print path #debugging only
        self.params = path.pathToScan.split("?")[1].split("&")
        out = list(map(lambda v: v.split("=")[0] +"=" + self.fuzz_vectors, self.params))
        dictpath[path] = out
    print dictpath
```

I'm getting an error of:

```
self.params = path.pathToScan.split("?")[1].split("&")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like a django queryset. Show `PathsOfDomain` model definition. Thanks.

Comment: can you give an actual example of what you want the dictionary to be after you are done?

Comment: Added some updated code, with an error message Im getting

Comment: If there's no querystring in the URL, then `split("?")[1]` will be out of range, as you can see, e.g. `"www.somesite.com".split("?")` equals `["www.somesite.com"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.params = path.split("?")[1].split("&")
```

should be

```
self.params = path.path.split("?")[1].split("&")
```

`path` is the PathsOfDomain object, but you need `path.path` which the actual string containing the path.

You should also look at the urlparse module which contains code to help parsing urls. You can use it simplify your code here.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippets, however, I'm still receiving an error of: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I can see the problem, but I'm going to have to see some initiative in figuring it out before telling you what it is.

Comment: I did some background on this error, it appears as I loop over the paths, its decrementing the list by one and thus throwing off the loop? Since its trying to access indices which no longer exist? Is this what is happening here Winston?

Comment: No, that particular issue isn't happening here. That happens when you somehow modify the list you are operating on. But you aren't modifying the list so you are safe from that.

Can you determine which path it fails on?

Comment: I really don't know if it even begins as it immediately fails upon executing

Comment: We know it begins, because the error pinpoints a line in the loop. So we must be inside the loop. It would be useful to determine which "path" is being processed at that time. An easy way to do that is to `print` path just before the line that give you an error. That will tell which path causes a problem.

Comment: Is the error the fact that a url may not adhere to what its trying to split on?

Comment: Yes. Think about what happens when the url doesn't have a "?" in it.

Comment: How can I modify my code to 'pass' that if a "?" isnt part of the path?